# How do I make a conditional compilation statement for release builds in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have some code that I want to skip if we're running a debug build (it's supposed to send an email but that requires an email server which is not available when debugging).

I tried all of these:

```
#if !DEBUG

#if RELEASE

#if not DEBUG
```

but all of them misbehaved (the code was either grayed out for a release build or not grayed out for a debug build).

I even tried

```
#if DEBUG
' dummy blank block
#else
' code goes here
#end if
```

but the code in the `else` section is always highlighted, even when I'm in debug mode...

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Instead of this, why not have a dummy mailserver set up which you can send to (even if the mails are never actually delivered, you could at least log it for testing or something). IMHO it's better to simulate the real environment as closely as possible, rather than having environment-specific code, because otherwise it's harder to verify that the "live" version of the code will actually work until you make it live.

Comment: `but the code in the else section is always highlighted` -> I've tested your last example and it works as expected. I also use those directives in various vb.net/c# projects and never had any problems. Did you set the configuration to "Release"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations

Comment: Yes, I did set the build configuration to release. I wonder if the syntax highlighting is just laggy because this is a 1600 line file? As for a dummy mail server, I suppose I could do that, but I'd still need to test which environment I'm in anyway so I know whether to call the dummy mail server or the real one, right?

Comment: " I'd still need to test which environment I'm in anyway so I know whether to call the dummy mail server or the real one, right"...not if you just stick the name of the server in your app settings, and then use a different config per environment (using config transforms in .NET, or different appSettings files in .NET Core)

Answer (score 0):

When switching to debug mode Visual Studio grayes the Else part because It wants to tell you that you are not in release mode that's why when you switch to release mode it grayes the first part because you're not in debug mode that's all
that was meant to help developpers (I don't know why you can just look up in the selected mode)

```
Dim blnDebuggin As Boolean = False
#if (DEBUG)
       blnDebuggin = true
 #else
       blnDebuggin = false
 #endif
```

You can also use this to identify the application running mode

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

and i hope this one should work too

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

Taken from here [Click me ^^][1]
[1]: https://forums.asp.net/t/1552928.aspx?How%20to%20know%20whether%20application%20is%20in%20release%20or%20debug%20mode%20using%20vb%20net%20code